# Fetching Data based on conditions using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to fetch data based on filter based queries. Right now I am using

```
 filter_stuff = {'url': 1, 'organization_name': 1, 'hum_pred':1, 'ml_pred':1, '_id': 0}
 myData = list(crawlcol.find({'hum_pred': 'null'}, filter_stuff))
```

This will fetch data where `hum_pred` have values `null`.

`hum_pred` and `ml_pred` will have values `valid` `invalid` or `null`

How is it possible to fetch data which has field values `hum_pred is null` and `ml_pred is valid or invalid`

**sample data**

```
[
 {"url":"www.example1.com","organization_name":"abc","ml_pred":"Valid", "hum_pred":"invalid"},
 {"url":"www.example2.com","organization_name":"gvg","ml_pred":"Invalid", "hum_pred":"null"},
 {"url":"www.example3.com","organization_name":"hsg","ml_pred":"null", "hum_pred":"null"},
 {"url":"www.example4.com","organization_name":"hga","ml_pred":"Valid", "hum_pred":"valid"},
 {"url":"www.example5.com","organization_name":"tre","ml_pred":"Invalid", "hum_pred":"valid"}
 ]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[{"url":"www.example2.com","organization_name":"gvg","ml_pred":"Invalid", "hum_pred":"null"}]
```

Comment: You can specify multiple conditions on multiple fields using `$or` and `$and` logical query operators.

Comment: @prasad_ Thankyou for the response.  Can you give me an example

Comment: Please feel free to refer the MongoDB Manual, for the usage and examples for the query operators.

Comment: I appied in this way `list(crawlcol.find({$and: [{$or: [{"ml_pred": "Valid"},{"ml_pred": "Invalid"}]}],{"hum_pred": "null"}}, filter_stuff))` but I am getting an error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Also, see PyMongo documentation for writing queries with Python specific syntax. With Python code one of the requirements is that the operators and field names must be within quotes; for example `"$or"`, `'hum_pred'`, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will be like

```
myData = list(crawlcol.find({"$and": [{"ml_pred": {"$ne": "null"}},{"hum_pred": {"$eq": "null"}}]}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Query

- you have strings for example `"null"`, so strings are used for `null`
- to check if equal with one of multiple values we can use `$or and $eq` or `$in` like bellow (`$in` is more compact for this use)

*if you have only 3 possible values for `ml_pred` the @imhans4305
answer is even shorter, so go for the other i think, this is how you could do it in general case.

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=625810d2f7e3c64c6511e185)

```js
find({"hum_pred": "null","ml_pred": {"$in": ["Valid", "Invalid"]}})
```

Comment: Thaank for the reply. Please upvote the question too